# Reading a RO property of a link ,how to extract the desired string

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft

UFT-vbScript- I am reading a getROproperty of a link  from an application.And the link has 300 different values following similar class pattern for many links like [PDF LLC- USA , [PDF MMB CANADA ,[PDF MCCS AUSTRALIA ,[PDF SSC MEXICO. [PDF ACCS MEXICO My question here is I just want to display the country name removing the other associated strings .How will I achieve this progamatically using vbscript. one way of doing this is using SPLIT fxn , but the real question is how will one know which pattern to choose from .

Answer (score 0):

You **should always** post a sample code which you have tried along with your question.

If there is always a space (" ") just before your country name, use space to split up like the below

```
strExtractedValue = "[PDF LLC- USA"
arrExtract = Split(strExtractedValue , " ")
strCountryName = arrExtract(2) ' the 3rd element
```

Comment: Thanks Mithilesh .With the help of RegExp and Split function I was able to get the desired output.

set oRegExp= new RegExp
oRegExp.global= True
oRegexp.Ignorecase = True 
oRegexp.Pattern=".PDF SMC -"
bMatch =oRegExp.Test(x)


If bMatch = TRUE Then
 temp = split(x,"[PDF SMC - ")
'msgbox (temp(0))
Print(temp(1))
End If